# How do I calculate the minimal distance to a rectangle in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I want to calculate the minimal distance to a rectangle in JavaScript:

```
--------
|      | <- Rectangle
--------

               * <- Point
```

But I only found a script to get the [distance to the center of a rectangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/calculate-distance-between-mouse-and-element/). Please try to avoid JQuery because I don't want to use it in my code.

Example: (distance to center)

```js
var distance = Infinity,
  rect,
  out;
document.mouse = {
  x: Infinity,
  y: Infinity
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { // set vars
  rect = document.getElementById("rect");
  out = document.getElementById("out");
}, false);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  document.mouse = {
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
    } // get mouse position
  distance = elementDistanceToCursor(rect) // get distance to element
  out.innerHTML = ["distance: ", distance].join(""); // show result
}, false);

function elementDistanceToCursor(elem) { // get distance to element center
  var b = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return Math.floor(
    Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(document.mouse.x - (b.left + (elem.offsetWidth / 2)), 2)
     +Math.pow(document.mouse.y - (b.top + (elem.offsetHeight / 2)), 2)
    )
  );
}
```

```css
div#rect {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
out {
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rect">
    <out id="out"></out>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the minimal distance from a rectangle to a point you use signed distances on each dimension, then compute the sqrt of squared sums.

```js
var distance = Infinity,
  rect,
  out;
document.mouse = {
  x: Infinity,
  y: Infinity
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { // set vars
  rect = document.getElementById("rect");
  out = document.getElementById("out");
}, false);

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  document.mouse = {
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
    } // get mouse position
  distance = elementDistanceToCursor(rect) // get distance to element
  out.innerHTML = ["distance: ", distance].join(""); // show result
}, false);

function elementDistanceToCursor(elem) { // get distance to element
  var b = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var dx = 0;
  var dy = 0;

  //Compute distance to elem in X
  if (document.mouse.x < b.left)
     dx = b.left - document.mouse.x;
  else if (document.mouse.x > b.right)
      dx = b.right - document.mouse.x;

  //Compute distance to elem in Y
  if (document.mouse.y < b.top)
     dy = b.top - document.mouse.y;
  else if (document.mouse.y > b.bottom)
     dy = b.bottom - document.mouse.y;

  return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
}
```

```css
div#rect {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
out {
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rect">
    <out id="out"></out>
</div>
```